# Django databases with multiple relations and ForeignKeys

Tags: python, django, database

I have multiple databases with different relations and I'm unable to figure out how to properly structure things to avoid problems in Django Admin.

Here is the design I want:

```
Category
 -> 'name'       (CharField)

Movie
 -> Multiple CharFields

CategoryLink
 -> 'category'   (ForeignKey -> Category)
 -> 'movie'      (ForeignKey -> Movie)
 -> 'prefix'     (ForeignKey -> Prefix) - Blank, Null
 -> 'number'     (DecimalField)

Prefix
 -> 'category'   (ForeignKey -> Category)
 -> 'prefix'     (CharField)
```

I want to achieve is a structure where:

- Each Category can have multiple CategoryLinks to Movies
- Movies can exist within any number of Categories any number of times.
- CategoryLinks can have a Prefix, but doesn't have to have one.
- Prefixes are limited to specific Categories
- Editing a Prefix for a specific Category has no effect on a prefix of the same name for a differ Category
- Categories can have multiple or zero Prefixes
- Prefixes can only be used by a CategoryLink if the Prefix.category == CategoryLink.category
- Unrelated Prefixes are hidden from Categories

My main issue is that when I try to limit the choices of Prefixes to only display choices relevant to the current Category I run into a wall. I can do it fine when editing a CategoryLink, but not when adding a new one.

If I try to limit the choices in the Admin Panel with something like this:

```
#admin.py
# ....
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PrefixForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    Prefix.objects.filter(category_id=self.instance.category.id)
```

It works fine while editing, but it throws an error whenever I'm in a form which has the ability to add new entries. Since the new entries doesn't have a defined category.id by virtue (I assume) of not existing yet Django throw an "RelatedObjectDoesNotExist" exception at me.

If I can get it to work while editing an existing Category that would be fine. I don't need to be able to create new CategoryLinks without having a Category already, but when I try I get the same error since I'm using a TabularInline class to include CategoryLinks into Category.

I'm willing to completely restructure everything to get this to work, as you can probably tell I'm new to Django so it's possible I'm thinking about this all wrong.

I asked a similar question last week that I thought I had figured out on my own, but it turned out I simply pushed the problem a step rather than solve it.

Is there a better way to structure my models or is there something I can do within admin.py to properly filter prefixes to categories? Let me know if you want to see all my code, it seemed a bit too much to post here.

I could "solve" this issue by turning CategoryLink.prefix into a CharField, but it would be so much cooler if I could have a separate model for Prefixes.

Here is my full Model.py (minus some irrelevant `__unicode__` stuff)

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def category_link_count(self):
        return len(CategoryLink.objects.filter(category_id=self.id))

    category_link_count.short_description = 'Movies in Category'


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Movie Title', max_length=300)
    year = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Year of Release',
                 max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)

class CategoryLink(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category Link"
        verbose_name_plural = "Category Links"

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    prefix = models.ForeignKey('Prefix', blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Movie Number', max_digits=2,
                                 blank=True, null=True, decimal_places=0)


class Prefix(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    prefix = models.CharField(verbose_name='Category Prefix', max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Prefix"
        verbose_name_plural = "Prefixes"
        ordering = ['-category']
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to have defaults for fields that have relations with other models, that way you can create a a `Category` and have an arbitrary `Prefix`. However, I think you have structured your models inappropriately.

`Category` has a ManyToManyField to `Prefix` which has a FK to `Category`. You don't need the FK. This is just one, but you can really simplify your organization. I don't know enough about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks. The ManyToManyField to prefix was an attempt at limiting the Admin Panel to only show Prefixes directly related to Categories, but that didn't work so I've removed it.

I can list the related prefixes below with an inline, but what I really want is to have an inline for CategoryLink under the CategoryAdmin which only shows Prefixes that has category_id equal to the specific category I'm editing.